# AWS RDS export to S3 Bucket creates parquet files with '.gz.parquet' termination causing download errors in Python, any solutions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I export an Aurora DB stored in RDS in AWS to an S3 Bucket and i got parquet files like the following

```
part-00000-8906a920-b82c-4626-9faf-61ff01231207-c000.gz.parquet
```

The problem is when trying to downloading this files with Python, CLI or using lambda function is getting errors because of the '.gz.parquet' termination.
If I change the name is working fine, anyone can suggest me a way to store this different or to change the name to multiple files ? (I have up to 4k partitions so i can't do it manually).

I want to move the files to another bucket that it is in another region, so I'm trying to do it download the files to local or by a lambda but due to this problem I'm not able to do it. Also I tried another approaches like Data Sync or exporting the database to the other bucket, but as they are not in the same region AWS doesn't allow this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be no reason for S3 behaving differently based on filenames. Please show us how you are attempting to download such a file and include the _exact_ error message you are receiving. By the way, if your goal is to copy files to another bucket, then you can use the `CopyObject()` command (or `aws cp` / `aws mv`) without needing to download the files.

Comment: You are right, the problem was that I was missing the KMS permission. As the export of the Aurora DB to S3 had been done using a secret key, I needed that permission to decrypt the data and download the parquet files. Thanks for the respond :)

Comment: Great to know you figured it out! Feel free to add your own Answer with enough details to help future readers.